# Spring boot and thymeleaf pagination and sorting

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sorting, pagination, thymeleaf

I am studying spring boot and making pet project and now I need do pagination and sorting. I am using thymeleaf in html page and I have some problem with Pageable and Sort field.

I have controller

```
@GetMapping
    public String showAllClassrooms(Model model, Pageable page) {
        Page<Classroom> classroomPage = classroomService.getAndSort(page);  
        model.addAttribute("classroomPage", classroomPage);
        return "classrooms-page";
    }
```

and Service method

```
    @Transactional
    public Page<Classroom> getAndSort(Pageable paging) {
        long totalElement = count();
        List<Classroom> classrooms = new ArrayList<>();
        if (paging.getSort().toString().contains("Address")) {
            classrooms = getAndSortByAddress(paging.getPageSize(), (int) paging.getOffset());
        } else {
            classrooms = getAndSortByCapacity(paging.getPageSize(), (int) paging.getOffset());
        }
        return new PageImpl<Classroom>(classrooms, paging, totalElement);
    }
```

and naviagion in page

```
<nav aria-label="..." th:object="${classroomPage}">
                <ul class="pagination  justify-content-center">
                    <li class="page-item" th:classappend="*{(getNumber == 0 ? 'disabled' : '' )}">
                        <a class="page-link" th:href="@{/classrooms/(page=*{getNumber-1}, size = *{size}, sort=*{sort})}">&laquo;</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"  th:classappend="*{(getNumber == getNumber ? 'active' : '' )}"> 
                        <a class="page-link" th:text="*{getNumber} + 1"  th:href="@{/classrooms/(page=*{getNumber}, sort=*{sort})}" ></a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"  th:classappend="(*{getNumber} == *{getTotalPages}-1 ? 'disabled' : '' )">
                        <a class="page-link" th:href="@{/classrooms/(page=*{getNumber+1} , size = *{size} , sort=*{sort})}">&raquo;</a>
                    </li>
                     <li class="page-item">
                        <form action="#" method="get" th:action="@{/classrooms/}"  
                            >
                            <div class="input-group">
                                 <input class="w-25 p-1" type="text" name="page" th:value="${classroomPage.getNumber+1}">
                                 <input type="hidden" name="size"  th:value="${classroomPage.size}">
                                 <input type="hidden" name="sort"  th:value="${classroomPage.getSort}">
                                 <span class="input-group-text" th:utext="${classroomPage.getNumber + 1}" ></span>

                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </li>       
                    
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

everything is working alright, but I have double direction in address field of browser, like this

```
http://localhost:8080/classrooms/?page=2&size=5&sort=Capacity:%20ASC:%20ASC:%20ASC:%20ASC:%20ASC:%20ASC:%20ASC:%20ASC
```

Thank you for you time, and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: You are making things too complicated imho. You are working around Spring Data functionality here instead of using it. Let your repository extend `PagingAndSortingRepository` and just call the `findAll(Pageable)` method instead o doing those things yourself in the service (and working around things).

Comment: Thank you :) I extend my repository from PagingAndSortingRepository  my code became symple simpler and smaller. But I still have problem with repite direction in Sort field : ASC: ASC. I think that is why I use thymeleaf not properly. I am passing field sort like String and Controller cant convert properly String to sort :(